# How to automate test cases for a dialog box message using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am actually new to selenium web driver and stackoverflow. I am working on automating test cases for a 'forgot password' feature which has a dialog box when unregistered email address is entered.

I want to validate the message 'This email is not registered!' in the dialog box ,but not sure how to proceed as i am using xPath which keeps changing for the message 'This email is not registered'.

This email account is not registered!

```
@Test
public void checkForgotPasswordWithInvalidCredentials() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='forgetBtn']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='emailInput']")).sendKeys("test@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='verify_btn']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);


    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='alert_box_14']/p")).isDisplayed();

}
```

In the above code, the Xpath for the alert message(.//*[@id='alert_box_14']/p) keeps changing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number keep changing you can use partial id

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@id, 'alert_box')]/p")).isDisplayed();
```